# View data from relational table using foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to fetch data from users table by user_id which is the foreign key in vehicle table. The relation is working properly like as when I insert data in the vehicle table then user_id also inserting as expected, but the problem is when I want to fetch data from users table using user_id.

**I used this SQL query for viewing data**

```
 <?php 
  $qry = mysql_query("select vehicle. *, users.zip AS zip from vehicle  JOIN users ORDER BY id DESC ");
  while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qry))

 {?>


  <tr role="row" class="even">

      <td style="display:none;"><?php echo $data['id'];?></td>  

      <td class="sorting_1">  <?php $datess = $data['create_date'];
         $old_date_timestamp = strtotime($datess);
         echo date('m-d-Y', $old_date_timestamp);?>

      </td>
      <td><?php echo $data['bid_type'];?></td>

      <td><?php echo $data['zip'];?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="bid-detail.php?id=<?php echo base64_encode($data['id']);?>" class="btn btn-success btn-small">$ Make Offer</a>
      </td>

   </tr>

<?php
 }
 ?>
```

This query displaying data, but **it's repeating one again and again**.

Anyone can help me please to solve the issue or any other easy solution for this.

Comment: You are using database functions that have been deprecated for more than 5 years. These functions don't even exist in the current version of PHP. Stop using mysql_* functions.

Comment: You need to specify a join condition; otherwise you get a cross-product of the two tables. Try `... JOIN users ON users.user_id = vehicles.user_id ORDER BY ...` And don't use the `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: @miken32 I am updating a site the site owner  didn't want to update this

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax its showing this error "Unknown column 'users.user_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: Use whatever the correct column is in table `users`. I had to guess since you didn't post your table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue in your query.

You have to add WHERE clause in your query which will match your PK of parent table with FK of child table.

Try This:

```
select v.*, u.zip AS zip from vehicle as v,users as u WHERE v.user_id=u.user_id ORDER BY v.id DESC
```

Comment: My pleasure @MuktoMona :)

Answer (score 0):

The query looks really wrong to me...

```
 "select vehicle. *, users.zip AS zip from vehicle  JOIN users ORDER BY id DESC "
```

This has merged both tables. To join them use something like this

```
"select * from vehicles as v, users as u where v.id = u.vehicle_id order by id desc"
```

or something similar. You need to specify two tables ie `vehicles` and `users` then `join` them on some column with the same type and hopefull where the same type means logically the same thing ie if it's vehicle id or a user id etc.